# Cannot see tabs or Settings drop-down menu

Tags: windows-terminal

In Windows CMD and Powershell, I don't see the tabs and Settings option.

What do I need to do to see them - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a [quick google search](https://superuser.com/questions/1683272/windows-terminal-has-no-title-bar-and-doesnt-show-tabs) confirmed, you need to disabled Focus Mode :

> Try pressing Ctrl+Shift+P to get the Command Palette, then find and select "Toggle Focus Mode".

Cheers

Comment: It doesn't do anything - tried in both Terminal and PS. I'm on Windows 10 Home.

Comment: I was running CMD - not Windows Terminal - didn't even know it existed.